# How to make context manager also as decorator without using classes in python 2.7?

Tags: python, decorator, contextmanager

I have some existing code written in following style, and it works as expected, I can use chunkUndo as context managers.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from functools import wraps

@contextmanager
def chunkUndo(mode='simple'):
    print 'mode:',mode
    print 'undo chunk start'
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print 'undo chunk end'

# this works
with chunkUndo():
    print 'do work here'
```

However, since I have a lot of already written context manager code like above, I don't want to change them into [class based contextDecorators](https://coderwall.com/p/0lk6jg/python-decorators-vs-context-managers-have-your-cake-and-eat-it). Instead I want to add a decorator to already decorated chunkUndo to make it a decorator function, something like:

```
def makeContextDecorator(f):

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        # some code here
    return wrapper

@makeContextDecorator
@contextmanager
def chunkUndo(mode='simple'):
    print 'mode:',mode
    print 'undo chunk start'
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print 'undo chunk end'

@chunkUndo
def  do_work():
    print 'do work'

do_work()
```

The end result is I can use `chunkUndo` both as decorators and context managers, possibly passing argument to it as well. How do I do that ?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want `chunkUndo` to still work as it does in the code at the top (in a `with` statement), after you've changed it to work in the code below? I suspect your `makeContextDecorator` function will need to be much more sophisticated in that case (maybe a class, rather than just a function).

Comment: Yes I want the above code still work. The goal is to make `chunkUndo` both work as `context manager` and `decorator`, but without using classes.

Comment: Why do you need to do it without using classes? I mean, I love pounding in nails with a spirit level as much as the next guy, but at some point you just need to do things the way the language wants you to do it.

Comment: It sounds like really, what you're looking for isn't "without using classes". It's "without writing a new class for each deco-manager". If you don't want any classes at all, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `chunkUndo` to work as both a context manager, and as a decorator that applies itself to the function it decorates, you'll need to make your `makeContextDecorator` function much more sophisticated. Here's a first attempt that would work in both of your examples:

```
from functools import wraps

def makeContextDecorator(cm):
    def wrapper(func=None):
        if func is not None:
            @wraps(func)
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                with cm():
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return inner
        else:
            return cm()
    return wrapper
```

Here's how it looks in action:

```
@makeContextDecorator
@contextlib.contextmanager
def foo():
    print("start")
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print("end")

with foo():
    print("with") # prints "start", "with", "end" on separate lines

@foo
def bar(x):
    print("bar", x)

bar(1) # prints "start", "bar 1", "end" on separate lines
```

This design only works with context managers that don't take any arguments.

You can make it work in `with` statements with arguments (you'd just need to change `wrapper` to accept `*args` and `**kwargs` style arguments), but it would be a bit awkward since you can't tell the difference between getting called with a single callable argument (e.g. `with foo(lambda x: x*2):`) and being invoked as a decorator.

It would be more difficult to accept arguments for the context manager when you're using the decorator syntax. That's because calling a decorator with arguments (e.g. `@foo("xyz")`) means that the decorator is actually a decorator factory. It needs to return something that works like a decorator (a function that modifies another function). But the returned value also needs to work like a context manager directly. You'd need to write a class that can do both at once, which is what you said you want to avoid.